# Failed to connect to repository Error performing command GitHub Jenkins Plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, repository

I am getting an error when inputting my repo location into the "Source Code Management > Git > Repository URL" section of a new Job. I have searched all around and tried many different URLs with no success.

ERROR:Failed to connect to repository : Error performing git command: C:\Program Files\Git\bin ls-remote -h https:

Comment: It looks like not your job but your jenkins configuration is broken. The pointer to git is missing the final `git` command. So instead of
`C:\Program Files\Git\bin` it should point to `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe` (not sure about git.exe or git.cmd - don't have a windows computer at my hands). Maybe check also https://filipin.eu/jenkins-windows-and-git

Comment: I tried that but again I got an ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. Can you please share the entire log?

Comment: FailedConsole Output

Started by user varsha
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\version2
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 43c82c6d-784c-4004-9c60-9d25eb6ed27c
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

Comment: > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/ # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.29.2.windows.2'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials github
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10

Comment: > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE                    this is the error which i got